# How to set a parameter in json when json is string format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, windows-phone-8

How to set a parameter in json this json is string type, I have using a c# code.

Here is my json;

```
double Latitude = e.current.Latitude;
double Longitude = e.current.Longitude;
string json = "{ \"device_id\" : \"nishant\",\"position\" : \"47.64325,-122.14196\" }";
```

How to set Latitude and Longitude in position 47.64325 and -122.14196

Comment: This line return a error Formate exception was unhandled   "FormatException"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use placeholder

```
double Latitude = 47.64325;
double Longitude = -122.14196;
string json = "{" + "\"" + "device_id" + "\"" + ":" + "\"" + "nishant" + "\"" + "," + "\"" + "position" + "\"" + ":" + " \"" + Latitude
                + "," + Longitude + "\"" + " }";
```

Comment: please give me solution

Comment: when i try to post your code it return  a  error the error is 
JSONObject["device_id"] not found

Comment: i get the problem thankyou sir the problem is device_id+ here i change to device_id

Comment: @NishantChandwani, sorry for you, I have edit it, there was a small distake, you try again. Wish you can mark it as anwser

Answer (score 3):

With `Newtonsoft.Json` lib and dynamics you can do something like this:

```
double Latitude = 11.1234;
double Longitude = 22.4321;
string json = "{ \"device_id\" : \"nishant\",\"position\" : \"47.64325,-122.14196\" }";

dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
jsonObject.position = Latitude.ToString() + ',' + Longitude.ToString();
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
```

Here is the working fiddle http://dotnetfiddle.net/Bosonr

Answer (score 0):

```
double Latitude = e.current.Latitude;
double Longitude = e.current.Longitude;
string json = "{ 'device_id' : 'nishant','position' : '" + Latitude + "','" + Longitude + "'}";
```

Comment: actually This type of json is not getting return a error i have using string type json this is proper json function . and i have using a post method and send this parameter on websevice. so this is not working

Comment: Can you say how you are posting the request.. Because there it might've gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with C# 11, you can use [interpolated raw string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#interpolated-raw-string-literals) to make this more terse and pretty removing all of the escaping and string concatenation.

```cs
  var latitude = 47.64325;
  var longitude = -122.14196;
  var json = $$"""{"device_id":"nishant","position":"{{latitude}},{{longitude}}"}""";
```